# Where am I allowed to put SQL code to drop a table in an AWS Data Pipeline?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-data-pipeline

I need to add some SQL code to drop a Redshift table in a Data Pipeline. Is there a specific field I can put it in? Can I put it in a Create Table SQL field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use [SQL activity](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-object-sqlactivity.html) for this. Attach [Redshift Database](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-object-redshiftdatabase.html) to it in it's 'database' field and use 'script' field to drop desired table.

Example:

```html
{
  "id" : "MySqlActivity",
  "type" : "SqlActivity",
  "database" : { "ref": "MyRedshiftDatabase" },
  "script" : "... drop table or any arbitrary sql query ... ",
  "schedule" : { "ref": "Hour" },
  "queue" : "priority"
},
{
  "id" : "MyRedshiftDatabase",
  "type" : "RedshiftDatabase",
  "clusterId" : "clusterId",
  "username" : "user_name",
  "*password" : "my_password",
  "databaseName" : "database_name"
}
```

Comment: Yeah I didn't see the button for Add Activity so I was getting confused where to put SQL code.

Answer (score 0):

Could you add more context on your activity?

You can run any arbitrary commands through a ShellCommandActivity.

Example:

## exit script on error

set -e

## 1. Install PSQL client

## sudo yum install postgresql93 -y

## 2. Run the sql statement in $RedShiftFile in Redshift

export PGPASSWORD=$REDPwd
psql -h $RedShiftHost -p $RedShiftPort -U $RedShiftUsr -d $RedShiftDb -f $RedShiftFile

Answer (score 0):

Could you add more context on your activity?

You can run any arbitrary commands through a ShellCommandActivity.

Example:

//exit script on error
set -e

//1. Install PSQL client
sudo yum install postgresql93 -y

//2. Run the sql statement in $RedShiftFile in Redshift
export PGPASSWORD=$REDPwd
psql -h $RedShiftHost -p $RedShiftPort -U $RedShiftUsr -d $RedShiftDb -f $RedShiftFile

Comment: I was trying to just insert SQL code, so a SQLactivity is more in line with what I'm trying to do. A ShellCommandActivity would just obfuscate things